# Creating unique IDs for a few elements on the document - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a document using mongoose, and I can't find a way to create unique IDs for a few elements on the document.

For an example:

```
Document {
_id: ObjectId(...),
title: "Post Title",
comments: [
        { NEEDED_ID: 1, value: "abc"},{ NEEDED_ID: 2, value: "abc"}
],
input: {
isInput: true,
NEEDED_ID: 3,
}
}
```

Hope you can help me out with it.

Comment: Are you trying to create unique `_id`?   Or unique vals for `NEEDED_ID`?   Is this a data randomization problem or an ID referential integrity issue?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Hi thanks for your comment, I'm not talking about the _id, but a key called "NEEDED_ID", and it should start from 1 and go up to the last time needed.
The counting will reset everytime I'm creating a new document.
Maybe I can return from the DB an key with the Index of the comment?

Comment: Ah.  So you want to create unique *field names*, e.g. `comments: [ {FLD1:1,value:1},{FLD2:2,value:"abc"]`   ?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti More like that `comments: [ {theSpecialKey:1,value:"a"}, {theSpecialKey:2,value:"b"}]`

Comment: Still a little uncertain.  You say "it should start from 1 and go up to the last time needed" then "reset ... creating a new document."   So why is `theSpecialKey` repeating over and over?   Suggestion:  edit the question and put in 2 docs that look the way you want them to look after creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need an id that automatically increments check auto-increment in mongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment

example from mongoDB docs above with Atlas:

```
// create collections
db.createCollection("students");
db.createCollection("counters");

// create trigger
exports = async function(changeEvent) {
    var docId = changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
    
    const countercollection = context.services.get("<ATLAS-CLUSTER>").db(changeEvent.ns.db).collection("counters");
    const studentcollection = context.services.get("<ATLAS-CLUSTER>").db(changeEvent.ns.db).collection(changeEvent.ns.coll);
    
    var counter = await countercollection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: changeEvent.ns },{ $inc: { seq_value: 1 }}, { returnNewDocument: true, upsert : true});
    var updateRes = await studentcollection.updateOne({_id : docId},{ $set : {studentId : counter.seq_value}});
    
    console.log(`Updated ${JSON.stringify(changeEvent.ns)} with counter ${counter.seq_value} result : ${JSON.stringify(updateRes)}`);
    };

// Replace <ATLAS-CLUSTER> with your cluster service name.

db.students.insert({
   "name":"Jhon Doe"
});
db.students.insert({
   "name":"David Smith"
});
db.students.insert({
    "name":"Amanda Herny"
});
// get students from atlas
db.students.find().pretty();
```

if you need to create a random id in node, you can use the `crypto` package.

Option 1:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

// create id
const _id = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
// '4a82db25ba403269c009db0129a032f3'
```

Option 2:

```
const { randomUUID } = require("crypto");

const uuid = randomUUID()  
// 'e92b8088-7fd2-40fd-ad87-2c16cbedfc94'
```

EDIT: regarding your comment, `randomUUID()` definitely generates a unique id everytime. Double check your implementation of it if it doesn't work for you. You can test uuid generation in a demo script like this:

```
const { randomUUID } = require("crypto");

numberOfIds = 5;

// generate five unique id's
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfIds; i++) {
  const uuid = randomUUID();
  console.log(uuid);

  // prints 5 id's
  // f0151ff5-2656-400f-b4e6-c5549324f8f9
  // a8223ae3-6259-4114-951b-8c12c3d932bf
  // 3a0404fd-6f5a-40d3-9726-c549f6d62ab4
  // 35178ac4-62d5-4654-938e-0ffac378751a
  // 458bf08f-07d2-4849-bf67-6f328ff93109
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, I've used uuid but it dosen't get a new id for each of them, but a constant one for each document, which dosen't work out for me.
I even thought creating a variable and increasing it everytime, but it didn't worked too.

Comment: hey, it definitely creates a unique one everytime, check my demo script added to my answer, and maybe try it in a fresh environment. + maybe update your node version, if you run an older one

Comment: Hi I'll try it just like you did, I'm trying to get a index number and not a long string, but currently I can't find a way doing it so I might use your way, thanks alot!

Comment: just read  your question again and that you probably want an incrementing number. check the link in my answer to mongoDB docs - maybe thats what you want.

Comment: I sure looks like a solution, haven’t seen the link till now. Thanks alot!